# Using Test::More, how do I print out a debug message in my tested function?

Tags: perl

I write some test cases for a function `foo`.

Some test cases fail, and to debug and find the problem, I wish to print some debug messages inside function `foo`.

My attempts are:

- Print to stdout, later I learned that `Test::More` does not want me to modify stdout.
- Print to stderr, my messages are not shown when I execute `make test`

I learned about `diag` `note` and `explain`, I did `diag('test')` inside `foo` however the message is not printed. Examples of them show that they are to be used inside test case function.

I really want to print a message in my `foo` when I run test case for it!

So what is the most correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You didn't explain why you couldn't use `diag`?

Comment: I thought `diag` only prints a message inside the test case function, however I want to print the message inside my function, not in the test case function.

Comment: use Test::More tests => 1;

    sub foo()
    {
        print 'hello, world';
        return 1;
    }

    ok(foo() eq 1, 'foo() eq 1'); prints 1..1
hello, worldok 1 - foo() eq 1. It works already.

Comment: huh??? There's no such thing as a "test case function."

Comment: by **test case functions** I think that he means the functions in his .t files and that he wants to  show messages from the functions that his *test case functions* are testing.

Comment: @Tudor Constantin, and what if it he does? They're both just subs. There's no such thing as a "test case function".

Comment: @ikegami - he most probably does not have access to `diag()` and `note()` from those functions and also doesn't want to add a `use Test::More` in them - but of course, these are just some assumptions

Comment: @Tudor Cosntantin, Why are you saying he'd want to use `diag` without loading Test::More!? (I personally think he shouldn't do either, but it's what he asked to do.)

Comment: He wants to show messages from his tested code and he can't. He tried with `diag()`, it works, but that is not accessible in his tested code, because production code rarely `use`s `Test::More`. @HowardGuo - is that a valid solution to add `use Test::More;` in your tested code and use `diag()`?

Comment: @Tudor Constantin, You didn't answer my question. Why do you think he can't start loading Test::More when he starts using `diag`?

Comment: @Tudor Constantin, (And of course, it *is* accessible in his tested code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's attention.

I figured this out finally..

In my function

```
sub foo {
    diag('hahahah');
}
```

In my test:

```
ok(Package::foo());
```

And I did not see 'hahahaha' output when I ran `perl Makefile.PL; make test`

I read perldoc of Test::More and noticed that the example usages of diag/note are from the test file, not from the tested function,and that confused me little bit: I thought diag/note could ONLY be used in test case, not in the tested function.

Then why did not 'hahahah' print out at first place?

The reason is that... I did not `use Test::More;` in the package of `foo`. After put the line in there, I could see 'hahahah' in output.

I did not receive warning about `diag not found`.

Answer (score 1):

ug, talk about bad separation of concerns. It would look like:

```
package My::Module;

sub some_func {
   ...
   Test::More::diag(...) if defined(&Test::More::diag);
   ...
}

...
```

I'd prefer to create a mechanism to pass the data to the caller. I once used a debugging hook to achieve something similar.

```
{
   my $diag;
   local $My::Module::DEBUG_HOOK = sub {
      my (...) = @_;
      $diag = ...;
   };

   is(My::Module::some_func(...), ..., ...)
      or diag($diag);
}
```

The module would look something like:

```
package My::Module;

our $DEBUG_HOOK;

sub some_func {
   ...
   $DEBUG_HOOK->(...) if $DEBUG_HOOK;
   ...
}

...
```

Bonus: You know have the option of only outputting the diagnostic information on error, or to switch between `note` and `diag` depending on whether the test is successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to a file:

```
open my $fh, '>>', '/tmp/test.log';
  print $fh "my awesdome message\n";
close $fh;
```

Although, your function might not get executed if you don't see the output on stderr

Answer (score 0):

I am using:
$ make test TEST_VERBOSE=1